# Flutter http.post never returns a response

Tags: http, asynchronous, post, async-await, flutter

im having a real problem with Flutter..

im using the 'http' library to issue HTTP requests to my Express server.
when im trying to send an HTTP POST request my server does receives it but my Flutter code just stop executing.

```
print("here");
http.Response response = await http.post(url, body:data);
print("got response!"); // Never executes
```

I don't see any errors in the Logcat, even if i use fake url or close my server down, the same result always happen. the execution just stop without any error.

Does anyone know why???

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.

The problem was that the server didn't close the connection and an Unhandled Exception was thrown after a while.

but, the exception didn't appear on the logcat until i updated my flutter version

Comment: Can you share the flutter version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var response = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url), body:data);
final statusCode = response.statusCode;
print('Response Status code: $statusCode');
```

Comment: can you share your url? If not have you used Postman to see what data if any is returned?